# Jar disappearing from libs (source) folder in Eclipse after adding it to build path - is it bug or my doing something wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I copied `httpcore-4.4.4.jar` into `libs` source folder in Eclipse (Photon, extends version) - like this:

[image]

As I see the jar is not on the build path. So I right-click on it and add it to the build-path. But *after that the jar disappears from the libs folder!*  Yes, now I can see this jar in `Referenced Libraries` in Project Explorer but the fact that it disappears from libs folder is confusing.

Is it a bug or a feature?  Or is it me doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Although everything works OK (despite that disappearing), it seems it was my mistake to make `libs` a *source* folder.

I should have made `libs` just a *plain* folder (File->New->Folder). Then everything works the same, but nothing suddenly disappears from that folder:

[image]

It is OK though to make a `resources` folder to be a source folder - the essence of source folder is that if Eclipse can't compile its content it would just copy it to output folder (`bin` by default).

Answer (score 0):

The disappearing jar is a feature, please see step 5 in the following link:

https://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

You might want to consider using a build/dependency management tool such as Maven, Ivy etc. which will manage dependencies to external libraries for you. This is especially useful if you are a group of people working on the code. If you use the lib folder, then you would have to add the libs to the source control system you are using, and add updates to libraries there. With Maven, you can just define which libs you want, and they will be downloaded and used automatically.